# Its possible get the last value clicked or pressed on all element in body with one command in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have a command to do this but this command get not only the last value get all change in elements clicked or typed.

I need to get only the last value clicked or typed, is it possible?

This is my command

```
$('body').on("click keypress",function(e){console.log(e.target.value);});
```

For example the values of target in input element get the last typed value or in select element get value or selected form.

My command get

```
input1 

typed a get a  input 1

typed b get ab  input 1


typed c get c input 2

typed f get abf input 1

typed d get cd input 2

select check box value options m get m
```

I need to know how I could get with one command get only the last part
in this example

Is **input 2** value cd **input1** value abf **check** value m

for example if I choose dropdown my command get value red and choose the same dropdown again get blue then my command record values red and blue ; but i only need the last for all elements that exist in body

I reefeer the last changed value or element ( dropdown ;checkbox or input ; etc )

Comment: What does last value mean?

Comment: the values of target for example in input element get the last typed value or in select element get value or selected form

Comment: this monitoring each change and get each value I need to get  only the last value

Comment: Isn't that what your example code does? It will log the last triggered event.

Comment: is true but get each change I need to know if exist a command for get the same but only the last part of each element

Comment: Could you try that again? That didn't make sense.

Comment: I put an example

Comment: Every time you trigger an event it is the last event. So when you type "a" then "b" then "c", each event is the last event until you press the next one.

Comment: Just to clarify ... get the last letter on the input ? if is checkbox get entire value ? if is select get option selected ?

Comment: That's how changed works though? Just use the changed event. You don't need to put an event on every single key pressed if you only want the result of the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily store them in an object. Only problem with my approach is they all need different classes or IDs. The real question is, why take this approach at all?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var last_data = {};

  function store_update(id_class, value) {
    if (value !== last_data[id_class]) {
      last_data[id_class] = value
    };
    console.log(last_data);
  }

  function getID(obj) {
      try {
          var id_class = $(obj).attr('id');
          if (!id_class) {
            id_class = $(obj).attr('class');
          }
          return id_class;
      } catch (ex) {
        return undefined;
      }
  }

  $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {  
    var id_class = getID(this);
    if (id_class) {
      store_update(id_class, e.key);
    }
  });
  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function () {
    var id_class = getID(this);
    if (id_class) {
      store_update(id_class, $(this).prop('checked'));
    }
  });
  
  $('select').on('change',function () {
    var id_class = getID(this);
    if (id_class) {
      store_update(id_class, this.value);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inp1' />
<input type='text' class='inp2' />
<input type='text' class='inp3' />
<input type='text' class='inp4' />
<input type='text' class='inp5' />
<input type='text' class='inp6' />
<input type='text' class='inp7' />
<input type='text' class='inp8' />
<input type='text' class='inp9' />
<input type='text' class='inp10' />
<select class='myselect'>
<option value='1'>test 1</option>
<option value='2'>test 2</option>
<option value='3'>test 3</option>
</select>
<input type='checkbox' class='inp11' />
<input type='checkbox' class='inp12' />
```

If this is incorrect please explain far more clearly.

---EDIT---

If the OP just wants the last committed value to an element then use

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('input, textarea, select').on('change', function () {
    
    if ( $(this).is('[type="text"], select') ) {
      console.log('You just changed my value to "' + this.value + '"');
    } else if ( $(this).is('[type="checkbox"]') ) {
      console.log('You just flagged my value to "' + this.checked + '"');
    }
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inp1' />
<input type='text' class='inp2' />
<input type='text' class='inp3' />
<input type='text' class='inp4' />
<input type='text' class='inp5' />
<input type='text' class='inp6' />
<input type='text' class='inp7' />
<input type='text' class='inp8' />
<input type='text' class='inp9' />
<input type='text' class='inp10' />
<select class='myselect'>
    <option value='1'>test 1</option>
    <option value='2'>test 2</option>
    <option value='3'>test 3</option>
    </select>
<input type='checkbox' class='inp11' />
<input type='checkbox' class='inp12' />
```

Comment: Hi very thankyou for your response   ;the problem in this is that this not include for example checkbox or dropdown select element ; this get typed elements I need to get the last element VALUE  typed or check or select for all elements with one command

Comment: my command get this the only problem Is that my command get this but also get the old values not only last value

Comment: for example if I choose dropdown my command get value red and choose the same dropdown again get blue  then my command record values red and blue ; but i only need the last for all elements that exist in body

Comment: So why don't you just grab the value of the elements when you need them and stop recording their data at all? If an input's value is "Red" and it's previous value was "Blue" but you only want "Red" then only grab the value "Red" after it has changed not while it's being changed. :)

Comment: Hi very thankyou for your response  ;But I will try to wait a little longer before choosing answer

Comment: The point of my command is that I wish to monitor all the changes in order to save me time by writing javascript

Comment: What is the point of your commands? I'm afraid none of us are understanding you. Just use the changed event and grab the elements entire value.

Comment: See the bottom of my latest revision

Comment: Glad it helped. Take care.

Comment: Take care too .